# How do I upgrade strawberry perl without wiping \perl\site\lib\ and \perl\site\bin\?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I downloaded the 5.12.3 installer to upgrade my 5.12.1 installation. After installing 5.12.3, my previously installed cpan modules are gone. Is this expected behavior? Should I be backing up my library before upgrading to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected behavior. Next time you can use "autobundle" feature of CPAN client, it will create list/bundle of modules to reinstall using CPAN client in new version.

Comment: Yech. I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 7):

I would claim that this ***should not be*** expected behavior.

The `site` directories are not part of the standard distribution and should not be touched by the distribution. Heck, it's even why the `site` directories even exist. Otherwise, why not simply download all of the modules to the same directory? Why make a distinction between the standard Perl modules and the modules you download from CPAN?

I too found this out the hard way when my personal modules -- modules that are not part of CPAN -- were blown away by my upgrade of Strawberry Perl. ActivePerl does it right -- not only not touching the `site` directory, but also adds in the Perl version to the standard module directory and the site directory.

Comment: If Strawberry is like AS, it doesn't use an arch. The site is therefore build-specific. It makes perfect sense to wipe it if you reinstall to the same directory.